# NativeScript: simple template not rendered

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

When calling a template via *ngFor, no matter how simple, it is not being rendered.

component.html:

> ```
> <Label text="hello world""></Label>
> ```

container.html:

> ```
> <StackLayout>
>     <GridLayout *ngFor="let obj of objs">
>         <!-- WORKS: -->
>         <Label text="hello world"></Label>
>         <!-- DOES NOT WORK: -->
>         <ns-component></ns-component>
>     </GridLayout>
> </StackLayout>
> ```

When using the snippet under , (the simple, non-template Label), for an array of 3 objects, I see three lines of "hello world". However, when calling the template rather than the simple Label, nothing is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have registered your component in the respective **module**.

For example

Creating the component with selector `ns-component`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "ns-component",
    moduleId: module.id,
    template: '<Label text="ns-component: Some Content"></Label>',
    styleUrls: ['./item.component.css']
})
export class ItemComponent  { }
```

And then register the component in the loaded module

```
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from "@angular/core";
import { NativeScriptCommonModule } from "nativescript-angular/common";
import { NativeScriptFormsModule } from "nativescript-angular/forms";

import { HomeRoutingModule } from "./home-routing.module";
import { HomeComponent } from "./home.component";

import { ItemComponent } from "./item.component"; // HERE

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        NativeScriptCommonModule,
        HomeRoutingModule,
        NativeScriptFormsModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        HomeComponent,
        ItemComponent // HERE
    ],
    schemas: [
        NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
    ]
})
export class HomeModule { }
```

And finally using it as required with the ***ngFor** structural directive.

```
<StackLayout>
    <GridLayout rows="100" *ngFor="let obj of [1, 2, 3, 4]" class="cell">
        <ns-component></ns-component>
    </GridLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

[Playground app demonstrating the above here.](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=A916Yn&v=2)

Comment: Well, I feel incredibly stupid now.

After double checking that my component was part of the module and another hour of more trial and error, I finally noticed that the referenced template for my inner component was that of the parent component. I copied the component and updated the selector, but not the templateUrl. Copy pasta for the win.